# Xrdp on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and then installed xrdp.  Whenever i tried to connect, either from another Ubuntu 20.04 box using either xfreerdp or krdc, or from a Mac, a black screen would show up, and then immediately disconnect.  i made sure i did not have any other sessions on the server going on at the same time.

After a while, i gave up and tried the script at:
https://www.c-nergy.be/products.html
it didn't make a difference

this is the only output from /var/log/xrdp.log

```
[20200529-18:17:16] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:192.168.0.216 port 45006 
[20200529-18:17:16] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.0.199 port 3389) 
[20200529-18:17:16] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389) 
[20200529-18:17:16] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem 
[20200529-18:17:16] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem 
[20200529-18:17:16] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled 
[20200529-18:17:16] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled 
[20200529-18:17:16] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 3, selected 1 
[20200529-18:17:16] [INFO ] connected client computer name: coruscant 
[20200529-18:17:16] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1004 flags 0xc0a00000 
[20200529-18:17:16] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff:192.168.0.216 port 45006: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
[20200529-18:17:16] [DEBUG] xrdp_00000506_wm_login_mode_event_00000001 
[20200529-18:17:16] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini 
[20200529-18:17:16] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file 
[20200529-18:17:17] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.0.199 port 3389) 
[20200529-18:17:17] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
```

thank you very much

Comment: int the past this has worked for me after a few updates to os this too has failed

Answer (score 23):

I was able to solve this issue by logging out of the desktop session for the machine before trying RDP.

Comment: This is true, but interesting. Why it is so?

Comment: Fine, but that didn't work for me. I have never seen xrdp work on ubuntu, or for that matter, on any linux. Black screen always.

Comment: @user289334 For me, ubuntu-desktop worked fine. The only problem with it was it was so very slow and decided to move to a lighter environment. And I got an error in Xubuntu Core.

Comment: I have the same. Even more interesting is that once I am logged through RDP I can't start a desktop session on the machine itself until I log out from the RDP session...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Maybe it doesnt allow access to system with same user from multiple places. To maintain one source of change. Its true for windows rdp connections as well. If you try to create an rdp connection with a windows ec2 instance, it will terminate any existing connections before letting you connect.

Answer (score 12):

I'd faced the same issue in my local server **Ubuntu 20.04 (Installed xubuntu-desktop)** and I had fixed it by executing the following command.

```
# echo "startxfce4" > ~/.Xsession
# chmod +x ~/.Xsession
# sudo systemctl restart xrdp.service
```

If you get a Warning Message **[Authentication is required to create a color managed device]** while connecting to the Ubuntu server through Xrdp, you need to execute the following commands to ignore it:

```
# cd /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/

# vi org.freedesktop.color.policy

Modify <allow_any> settings from auth_admin to yes.

<defaults> 
      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>

# reboot the system
```

Comment: The only solution that has worked for my after 3 hours looking for one. Thanks a lot man

Comment: RDP connection exits and will not connect at all after doing this.

Comment: Well, this worked! Thanks!

Comment: Line two needs to have a capital X

Comment: I tried `sudo vim /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.color.policy` and then changed `auth_admin` to `yes`. Let's see if this works.

Comment: This is also interesting: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp

Comment: Do not forget to `$ sudo apt install xfce4-session`

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be possible to allow multiple sessions so that you don't have to logout or end up in the blackscreen. Worked on my 20.04 LTS just by adding two lines into the startwm.sh.

```
nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

Add in the very top:

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

then:

```
sudo systemctl restart xrdp
```

Credits to [Peter Bennett](https://www.blogger.com/profile/09241915433449725123) @[catch22cats](http://catch22cats.blogspot.com/2018/05/xrdp-blank-screen-with-ubuntu-1804.html), thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on a fresh 20.04 LTS install today. Thanks! (Also: sudo systemctl restart xrdp) Ah, but the script by Griffon linked to by Luis Pereira is even better. It fixes this problem and others, and even sorts out the Terminal background colours, and has the option of a prettier login dialog.

Comment: Worked for me also with a `systemctl restart`. Does anyone know if I can log out of other sessions?

Comment: Likewise, worked great for me... it gives certificate errors after on the connecting PC, but compared to being stuck unable to get out of the blank screen on the Linux machine, I'll take it, thanks :)

Comment: Kind of worked for me but after seeing the desktop it disconnected after 20-30 seconds. Disclaimer - I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a crappy Technexion Android Things device and it's a miracle it's still running (WiFi is bust, external screen is bust, I'm just trying to breathe some more life into it).

Comment: Problem with the above is that I'm not allowed to open the browser afterwards.

Comment: @AhmedEbaid Execute 'sudo apt install firefox' in your WSL terminal and the default browser will be firefox. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

After many tries and some fixes I was able to rdp but:

1. **Password was requested** way to many times
2. **Side bar** didn't fill up the whole screen

So I found this [xRDP installation script](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15978) that **works perfectly**!
Credits to [Griffon](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?author=1)!!

#### Just download, unzip and run:

```
wget https://www.c-nergy.be/downloads/xrdp-installer-1.2.2.zip
unzip xrdp-installer-1.2.2.zip 
bash xrdp-installer-1.2.2.sh
```

Comment: This is great! (Best to visit the website and download the latest version.) It fixes a bunch of problems like the Terminal background colour, and it even has the option of a prettier login dialog. There are still problems, though. I had to turn off screen lock.

Comment: Couple issues: 1) Installer version is old. Perhaps link to https://www.c-nergy.be/products.html 2) Prob'ly better to just refer people to the site because the instructions to download a zip and run the contained script is highly suspicious. It made me think this was a malware post. I eventually stumbled upon Griffon's answer through Google searching.

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. Remove previously installed xrdp:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable xrdp
$ sudo systemctl stop xrdp

$ sudo apt purge xrdp
$ sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-input-all
$ sudo apt purge xorgxrdp
```

#### 2. Re-install xrdp & required packages:

```
$ sudo apt install xrdp
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
$ sudo apt install xorgxrdp
```

You also need to grant access to the **/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key** file for **xrdp** user. It is available to members of the **ssl-cert** group by default.

```
$ sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert           # add xrdp into ssl-cert group
```

```
$ sudo systemctl start xrdp            # start xrdp service
$ systemctl is-active xrdp             # check xrdp state
...
active
```

```
$ sudo systemctl enable xrdp           # start xrdp on system start
```

#### 3. Reboot system:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

#### 4. Firewall configuration:

You need to open access on port 3389.

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3389
```

It is more secure to open it only for your IP address or network. For example:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 10.5.5.0/24 to any port 3389
```

The best practice is to use an SSH tunnel to connect to the remote desktop and make xRDP listen only for local connections.

#### 5. Setup your RDP-client

**Please note that in some cases the user who will connect to xRDP must log out before doing so!**

- Connect to your server using any RDP client.
- Enter the user credentials of your Ubuntu computer.
- Now you can see the remote desktop initial screen.

#### Related commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl status xrdp           # display current xrdp status

$ sudo systemctl start xrdp            # start xrdp service
$ sudo systemctl stop xrdp             # stop xrdp service
$ sudo systemctl restart xrdp          # restart xrdp service

$ sudo systemctl enable xrdp           # enable xrdp on system start
$ sudo systemctl disable xrdp          # disable xrdp on system start
```

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: This guide is almost complete, it is only missing one step: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/764#issuecomment-841870212

Answer (score 0):

This is a big problem to many useres.
I found out an error on my systems.
I am using 2 Odroid C2 computers. I had the same issues. I installed from scratch and everything was ok. Then i did something not related to Remotedesktop and after that i could not log anymore.
The last time i had the system working fine and i changed the IP adress from xxx.xxx.xxx.094 to xxx.xxx.xxx.096
I could not log in via Remotedesktop.
I had the second system running good, so i startet to compare files
in my case the /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh had a complete different content. It looked like it was copied over with a different text.
Unfortunetly i got not further in it.
I restored this file and now it is working fine again.
There are so many tips for this problem, so just check that file.

Comment: and we are all wanting to know what it should like like since you have given us the task of 'checkin' it

Answer (score 0):

Install Xrdp Server again.

root@ubuntu:~# `apt -y install xrdp tigervnc-standalone-server`

Start Xrdp Server.

root@ubuntu:~# `systemctl enable xrdp`

Connect from other clients.

Comment: This does not add anything new, and has far less detail than the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution. This works for me since Ubuntu 18.X.
The answer to this funny thing maybe simpler than you think.

It is a password complexity and language problem. Around 2019-2020 the rules for password authentication for user accounts are pushed up. I think in Debian other than Ubuntu. But anyway the XORG stuff is pretty old and maintenance rare, it seems to me that leads into some issues and I assuming the following.

1. XORG is Debian based.
   While processing the login to the guest
2. XORG has no error handling for short and non complex passwords.
3. XORG ignores the language of the host system.

This works for me.

- 9 characters including numbers
- And at least character of special characters i.e. !"§$%&/ etc.
  Since I changed my simple user password in ubuntu from:
  funnR301
  to  funnR301$   (this works for german keyboard layout. See hint below!)
  There were no more black screen issues!

There are some more traps for i.e. german users or other with non english keyboard layout. Because the Xorg authentication window always use the englisch layout. This leads to some restriction for your password because the most of the special characters (!"§&..) are at different positions on non englisch layout keyboards. Also Y and Z are reversed in german layouts.

Cheers

Answer (score -3):

Try to install xrdp package by using sudo instead of root user. This works perfectly fine & tested on MAC (Microsoft Remote Desktop) & Window 10.

Link: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-remote-desktop-access-from-windows-10

Comment: Why do you think OP installed any way other than using `sudo apt install xrdp`?